# Shanks Algorithm for composite orders

Tags: discrete-logarithms

Can the Shanks algorithm for discrete logarithm problem (baby-step/giant-step) be used for composite orders?

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step),  "Usually the baby-step giant-step algorithm is used for groups whose order is prime. If the order of the group is composite then the Pohlig–Hellman algorithm is more efficient."

Is the above statement true? I have been trying to understand why the Shanks algorithm may not be used for composite orders, but I have not been able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Shanks algorithm can only be used for one piece functions, are you aware of this?

Comment: Not really, could you please elaborate?

Comment: it was a joke about a famous manga.

Comment: ahh :D wasn't aware of that till I accidentally searched "Shanks" instead of "Shanks Algorithm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shank's algorithm can be used for any group, it does not use any specific properties. The same is true for the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm. Suppose we have a group of order $$r=\prod_ip_i^{e_i},$$
then Shank's algorithm is usually presented to have complexity $O(\sqrt{r})$ (although it really is a time-memory trade-off) while Pohlig-Hellman has complexity $$O\left(\sum_ie_i(\log{r}+\sqrt{p_i})\right).$$
Note that Pohlig-Hellman generally does better for composite order, so there is little reason to use Shank's in that case. For prime order groups Pohlig-Hellman doesn't really do anything, so you can just use Shank's.